# reStructuredText not respecting subheadings

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docutils

Here's a simple reST snippet:

```
deleting this line causes all subheadings to be rendered as h1 tags

I should be an h1
=================

I should be an h2
-----------------
foo            

I should also be an h2
----------------------
foo
```

and here's a demonstration of it being rendered:

with initial line: http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=ff67380d732a33c7844f350c240804d0
without initial line: http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=550ea2c1b4233affdce1d158c5dc4d99

I'm rendering reST using the following Python:

```
from docutils.core import publish_parts
parts = publish_parts(rest_content, writer_name="html")
html_snippet = parts['html_body']
```

How do I get subheadings (specifically, `<h2>` tags) without the initial line? Do have provide two levels of hierarchy above the subheadings? Naively providing a page header doesn't help: http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=e874f6eaad17c8ae7fd565f9ecb2212b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't promote the 1st title to document title.

Note the **settings_overrides** param passed to **publish_parts()** in the example below:

```python
rest_content = """
I should be an h1
=================

I should be an h2
-----------------
foo


I should also be an h2
----------------------
foo
"""

from docutils.core import publish_parts
parts = publish_parts(rest_content, writer_name="html",
        settings_overrides={'doctitle_xform':False})
html_snippet = parts['html_body']

print(html_snippet)
```

And the output:

```html
<div class="document">
<div class="section" id="i-should-be-an-h1">
<h1>I should be an h1</h1>
<div class="section" id="i-should-be-an-h2">
<h2>I should be an h2</h2>
<p>foo</p>
</div>
<div class="section" id="i-should-also-be-an-h2">
<h2>I should also be an h2</h2>
<p>foo</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know about that setting, let alone that it was on by default. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. The accepted solution did not work for me. However, the following code did:

```
content = publish_parts(
    rest_content,
    writer_name='html',
    settings_overrides={'initial_header_level': 2})
html = content['html_body']
```

Answer (score 0):

ReST doesn't care what symbol you use for each level, "=" is merely a convention. So if you remove the first one it then sees "-" as denoting a h1. I don't think there is a way around this unfortunately.

Comment: Any symbol at all? Are you saying that the string `deleting this line` is treated as a heading? If not, why does removing that line change the heading rendering?

Comment: No, it has to be a series of non-alphanumeric characters, e.g. ===== or ~~~~~. See the [ReST docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickstart.html#sections)